# RestClient works but HttpWebRequest doesn't

Tags: c#, webrequest

This code works:

```
 var source = "https://jade.io/xml/au-qld-dc.xml";
        
 var client = new RestClient(source);
 var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
 IRestResponse resp = client.Execute(request);
 Console.WriteLine(resp.Content);
```

The xml is retrieved and displayed in the Console.
But this code doesn't work:

```
HttpWebRequest httpsRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(source);
httpsRequest.Method = "GET";
var response = httpsRequest.GetResponse();
```

It throws a 403 (Forbidden) error...

I'd like to know why it doesn't work, because I have some legacy code using WebRequest, and before replacing all that code with RestClient, if there is an easy fix...

Comment: For example, I think `RestClient` will add default User-Agent header, while HttpWebRequest will not.

Comment: You can use a network sniffer such as Wireshark or Fiddler to inspect the difference between the two http calls. Use that to correct the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add UserAgent header and it will work.

```
var source = "https://jade.io/xml/au-qld-dc.xml";
HttpWebRequest httpsRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(source);
httpsRequest.Method = "GET";
httpsRequest.UserAgent = "Test";
var response = httpsRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: thanks, it works now!
but what is weird is that it doesn't work with this UserAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36";
Do you know why?